# AddEventListener is fired but changing UI of one Div and not another

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to toggle the background-color of 2 divs together using `addEventListener` and `.style` property fetching via JS. However, I am able to do so in 1st div but not in 2nd one. Why? The code is same, the elements are same, then why only happening in 1st Div???

```js
 document.querySelector('button').addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.querySelector('div').style.background === "orange"
  ? document.querySelector('div').style.background = "pink"
  : document.querySelector('div').style.background = "orange";
 });
```

```css
div {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  margin:20px;
  border:2px solid black;
  display:inline-block;
  background:orange;
}
```

```html
<button>ok</button>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`querySelector` returns the first matching element. Use `querySelectorAll`, it will return a collection of all the matching elements.

You will then need to iterate over the collection and set styles on each individual element in the collection

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
let color;

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  divs.forEach(d => {
    if (!d.style.background || d.style.background === 'orange')
      color = 'pink';
    else
      color = 'orange';
    
    d.style.background = color;
  })
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<button>ok</button>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: sure, give me a minute

Comment: Interestingly I found, 1st click doesn't set 'pink'. As `item.style.background = ""` (blank). Can we fix it? As this works 2nd time onwards.

Answer (score 2):

You should use with `querySelectorAll` and `forEach` function. Like this:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(p => {
      p.style.background == "orange" ?
      p.style.background = "pink" :
      p.style.background = "orange";
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<button>ok</button>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Why 1st click is does not works? Because `element.style.background` looks to inline style. Since there is no inline-style at first it enters the else state and assigns inline-style. Check this out

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(p => {
      p.style.background == "orange" ?
      p.style.background = "pink" :
      p.style.background = "orange";
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<button>ok</button>
<div style="background: orange;"></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Interestingly I found, 1st click doesn't set 'pink'. As `item.style.background = ""` (blank). Can we fix it? As this works 2nd time onwards.

Comment: Yep, got it ... but is there any way, this works even if I am picking style from some 'internal css' or 'external css file'. Afterall I am only finding property which still anyways be interpreted by browser?

Comment: @Deadpool I don't think. Because when you get the color of the element from an external css file, it gives you as rgba. Not hex or named color.

Answer (score 2):

You could go with a `forEach()` loop and check every element in the list. `querySelector` takes the first element it finds while `querySelectorAll` gets all elements and put them in a node list, it looks something like this then `[element1, element2, element3...]` so you can loop through

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(element => {  
     !element.style.background  || element.style.background ==="orange"
     ? element.style.background = "pink"
     : element.style.background = "orange";
  })

 });
```

```css
div {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  margin:20px;
  border:2px solid black;
  display:inline-block;
  background:orange;
}
```

```html
<button>ok</button>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Interestingly I found, 1st click doesn't set 'pink'. As `item.style.background = ""` (blank). Can we fix it? As this works 2nd time onwards. -- like other 2 answers.

Comment: @Deadpool yeas, i made an check with `||` if its undefined or empty